# How to open a System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection with Active Directory Universal Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, ado.net, azure-sql-database, system.data

I was using the below code to connect to SQL Azure DB that was using Active Directory Integrated Authentication.

```
private string GenerateConnectionString(string databaseName, string serverName)
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    sqlConnectionBuilder.DataSource = string.Format(
        "tcp:{0}.database.windows.net",
        serverName);
    connBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
    connBuilder.Authentication = SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryIntegrated;
    connBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 30;
    return connBuilder.ConnectionString;
}
```

The authentication is changed from Active Directory Integrated Authentication to Active Directory Universal Authentication to support multi-factor authentication.

I see the enumeration 
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationMethod` doesn't have a value for Active Directory Universal Authentication. Is it possible to still use the `System.Data.SqlClient` to connect to the DB? If yes, what is
the change I have to do in the code?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

ActiveDirectoryInteractive authentication method is available since the .NET Framework 4.7.2. Not sure if it is the same as "Universal" or not.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.2 was not released when this question was first asked. Also, Active Directory Universal Authentication is indeed the same as ActiveDirectoryInteractive. See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/index#sql472

Answer (score 0):

As of August 2020, there's a better way to connect to Azure SQL DB's or Azure Synapse DW (SQL pools). By using the [MSOLEDBSQL driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) (which you may redistribute along with your application), your application can perform interactive/MFA authentication using the normal System.Data.OleDb objects:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
...
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=sqlserver.database.windows.net;User ID=user@domain.com;Initial Catalog=database;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive");
```

In fact, this is the recommended way of connecting to any Microsoft SQL product programatically, as both SQLOLEDB and SQLNCLI (aka. "SNAC") have been deprecated.